# In python what format is dtype(S3)?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I get the following error when specifying a pandas dataframe column for the size argument in a matplotlib scatter plot:

> "Cannot cast array data from dtype('S3') to dtype('float64') according
>   to the rule 'safe'"

The column in question is float64. I have never heard of dtype('S3') before.

Comment: It looks like a zero-terminated bytes of length 3: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.dtypes.html

Answer (score 0):

`dtype('S3')` is a string. Interpreting the question, you are doing something like

```
plt.scatter(..., s="ColumnName")
```

This produces the error, because `"ColumnName"` is a string, and not an array of numbers, as required.

Instead provide the number array

```
plt.scatter(..., s=df["ColumnName"].values)
```